# Error al intentar instalar git en Centos 7

Tags: git

Buenas, estoy intentando instalar el controlador de versiones git en Centos 7 pero al ingresar yum install git me sale el siguiente error:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum install git
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.globo.com
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror.globo.com
 * epel-source: mirror.globo.com
 * epel-testing: mirror.globo.com
 * epel-testing-debuginfo: mirror.globo.com
 * epel-testing-source: mirror.globo.com
No existe disponible ningún paquete git.
Error: Nada para hacer
```

He habilitado todos los repositorios de epel para intentar instalar git pero me sale el error de paquete no encontrado ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Podrias tratar de instalarlo bajando el código fuente, te puede servir esta guía. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7

Comment: ¿Has modificado los repositorios? Al parecer está en los oficiales y no hay que hacer nada más para instalarlo, ¿Seguro que tienes los correctos?

Comment: Tengo los siguientes repositorios, yo hasta el momento no modifiqué nada salvo otro compañero, estos son los repositorios de mi listado local.repo       remi-php71.repo, remi.repo.rpmnew, epel.repo, remi-php54.repo  remi-php71.repo.rpmnew, remi-safe.repo, epel-testing.repo , remi-php70.repo, remi.repo

Comment: Que te devuelve `yum search git`?